# How to send radio button value from form to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="tab"><h4>Zip Code</h4>
    <p><input type="text" class="text1" placeholder="Enter zip code..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="zipcode"></p>

  </div>
 <div class="tab"><h4>How long have you been planning to sell your property?</h4>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb" value="1-3 months"  class="option-input radio" checked/> 1-3 months</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb" value="4-6 months" class="option-input radio"> 4-6 months</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb" value="more than 6 months" class="option-input radio"> more than 6 months</p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="tab"><h4>Type of property?</h4>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb1" value="Single Family House" class="option-input radio"  checked/> Single Family House</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb1" value="Condo" class="option-input radio"> condo</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb1" value="Mobile" class="option-input radio">Mobile</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb1" value="Townhouse" class="option-input radio">Townhouse</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="rdb1" value="Multi-units" class="option-input radio">Multi-units</p>
   
  </div>
```

I do not receive radio button value in an email. all other text box, email and phone is shown by run this above code but the main issue is there with radio button.

If i comment the radio tags then the code runs perfectly, with radio i received only email without any data. also please check the value of radio button, is it contain space between two words is yes then how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Get the radio button value

```
var rdb = document.getElementsByName('rdb').value;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rdb"]:checked').value
```

Comment: I use this code for radio button 
$rdb_value = $_POST['rdb'];
$rdb_value1 = $_POST['rdb1'];

$Body .= $rdb_value;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "How many bedrooms?: ";
$Body .= $rdb_value1;

Comment: can you please add your php code by editing the same question?

Comment: $EmailFrom = "test@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "xyz@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Test";

$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$rdb_value = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb']));
$rdb_value1 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb1']));
$rdb_value2 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb2']));
$rdb_value3 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb3']));
$rdb_value4 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb4']));
$rdb_value5 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb5']));
$rdb_value6 = trim(stripslashes($_POST['rdb6']));

Comment: I use multiple radio buttons and divide form in some tabs

Comment: I received 2 emails: 1st is empty on page load and 2nd with other values and one radio value.